# Visual studio - background-image issue

Tags: html, css, razor

I tried to do an animated div with background-image and after some attempts the "url(../pic1.jpg);" part is not giving the picture witch is added to project. On VS Code it works fine, and after I put any URL to picture for example from google it also works. What is wrong?

Code Here:

```
<style>
    .huge-ball {
        position: absolute;
        height: 300px;
        width: 300px;
        border-radius: 100%;
        z-index: 5;
    }

    .left-bottom {
        left: -60px;
        bottom: -60px;
        background-image: url('../pic1.jpg');
    }

    .right-bottom {
        right: -60px;
        bottom: -60px;
    }

</style>

<div>
    <div>
        <div class="left-bottom huge-ball">

        </div>
        <div class="right-bottom huge-ball">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
background-image: url('../pic1.jpg');
```

Depending on where the image is relative to the compiled stylesheet, the path in the url() bit will need to change. If the image is in the same folder as the stylesheet, then the style would just be the below.

```
background-image: url('pic1.jpg');
```

It may be helpful to understand [relative/absolute paths](https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/) if that is the issue here.

Comment: The cshtml files are in folder out of witch i need to go back to acces the image. Nothing is wrong here. Maybe " url('../pic1.jpg') " is just wrong.